# Reallocation_Event_count has a large value while Reallocated_Sector_Count is zero

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I was checking my laptop's HDD (Seagate ST500LT012-1DG142) when I found out that the `Reallocation_Event_count` has a large value while `Reallocated_Sector_Count` is zero.

```
$ sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sda | grep -i reall
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x000f   076   076   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       21714 (35893 0)
```

[image]

The drive is from Seagate, and here is a shot from SeaTools:

[image]

As far as I know from [here](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9105):

> Reallocated Sectors Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the count of reallocated sectors (512 bytes). When the hard drive finds a read/write/verification error, it marks this sector as "reallocated" and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area).

Then why `Reallocated_Sector_Count` is zero? What else might cause these reallocated event counts?

Comment: Could you please add maker and model of the harddrive in question?

Comment: The operating hour counter looks wild. I suggest using _smartmontools_ (`smartctl`) to verify the values. The SMART data could be corrupted. // Please also provide the exact model of the drive.

Comment: @DanielB `smartct` shows the power on hours like: `22370 (8 170 0)`. It's a seagate: `ST500LT012-1DG142`

Comment: That sounds much more plausible. Please check the other values using`smartctl` then. Other software is obviously misinterpreting the data.

Comment: As for `Reallocation_Event_count`, the output of `smartctl` is `21714 (30258 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reallocation Event Count is a count of the **attempts** to transfer
data from a bad sector to a special reserved area (spare area).
This counts both successful and unsuccessful attempts.

It seems on the surface like your disk firmware is attempting to
remap sectors and failing, meaning that the disk is in a very
sad state.

Nevertheless, the count is too high. It's unlikely that so many
attempts were done and none have succeeded, when the disk is
supposedly working without failure.

I would guess that your disk firmware is using this SMART
parameter in a non-standard way for data which does not relate
to reallocation attempts.
If you can find a SMART display utility by the manufacturer
of the disk, it might give a better analysis of its status.

My advice would be to continue monitoring the disk for errors, but
I don't see here a reason for junking it.

Comment: I guess you are probably right, The drive is from seagate and I updated my question with a shot from **seatools** (software from seagate to check smart). sadly it does not provide any label for the attribute that I'm looking for.

Comment: At least the app doesn't call it "Reallocation Event Count", so you can have more confident that the disk is in good shape, whatever is that parameter. I found [here](https://www.hdsentinel.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8137): "The change of the mentioned attribute (196 Reallocation event count) is completely normal for some particular Seagate models, especially (but not limited to) hard disks used in some Lenovo notebooks - as they have special firmware which uses this value for other purposes, not to indicate real problems.".